# how to send integer type data in xml

Tags: c#, xml

I am creating XML to send data. The data contains multiple datatypes as string, integer and decimal. My XML format and c# code to create it as follows.

```
<root>   
  <data>     
    <struct>        
      <PartnerCD></PartnerCD>         
      <UserName> </UserName>        
      <Password> </Password>      
      <Action> </Action>        
      <OfficeCD></OfficeCD>        
      <ChannelCD></ChannelCD>      
      <Token></Token>       
      <Notes> </Notes>        
      <Products>         
        <Product>
          <ProductID></ProductID>
          <SVA></SVA>
          <Amount></Amount>
        </Product>                
     </Products>      
   </struct>   
  </data> 
</root>
```

And my c# code is

```
 public static string CreateRequestXML(string partnerCd, string userName, string password, string action, string productId, string token, string sva, string amount)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();

        XmlElement elemRoot = doc.CreateElement("root");
        XmlElement elemData = doc.CreateElement("data");
        XmlElement elemStruct = doc.CreateElement("struct");
        XmlElement elemProducts = doc.CreateElement("Products");
        XmlElement elemProduct = doc.CreateElement("Product");

        doc.AppendChild(elemRoot);
        elemRoot.AppendChild(elemData);
        elemData.AppendChild(elemStruct);
        //Insert data here
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemStruct, "PartnerCD", partnerCd);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemStruct, "UserName", userName);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemStruct, "Password", password);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemStruct, "Action", action);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemStruct, "Token", token);
        elemStruct.AppendChild(elemProducts);
        elemProducts.AppendChild(elemProduct);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemProduct, "ProductID", productId);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemProduct, "SVA", sva);
        InsertDataNode(doc, elemProduct, "Amount", amount);

        return doc.OuterXml;
    }

    private static void InsertDataNode(XmlDocument doc, XmlElement parentElem, string nodeName, string nodeValue)
    {
        XmlElement elem = doc.CreateElement(nodeName);
        elem.InnerText = nodeValue;
        parentElem.AppendChild(elem);
    }
```

and am getting the result as

```
<root>
  <data>
    <struct>
      <PartnerCD>123</PartnerCD>
      <UserName>api</UserName>
      <Password>pass</Password>
      <Action>token</Action>
      <Token>4847898</Token>
      <Products>
        <Product>
          <ProductID>123</ProductID>
          <SVA>e8a8227c-bba3-4f32-a2cd-15e8f246344b</SVA>
          <Amount>700</Amount>
        </Product>
      </Products>
    </struct>
  </data>
</root>
```

I want the PartnerCD and ProductId elements as integer and Amount element as decimal.  I have tried XMLNodeType but no use.

Comment: Both those nodes look like they have integer data in them to me - whats the problem exactly? And `Amount` is whatever you have passed in to this method -looks like it had the value `700`

Comment: You mean you'd like `Amount` to be present in the XML with decimal places?

Answer (score 2):

Well the data type is irrelevant in the XML as such, it's all defined in the schema it uses, that's where the declaration of expected data types are stored.

So if you have a XSD that says that `/root/data/struct/PartnerCD` is of type `xs:int` then you will get validation errors upon validating the file. The XML itself is just a container of all data, it doesn't include the meta information. You CAN define it manually, but the Point is beyond me in about 99.99% of the cases, and it's more or less a bastard of XML, like MSXML that will understand what you're up to.

Answer (score 1):

Xml has no concept of "data type" natively, the `XmlNodeType` you refer to is what type of *Node* it is (such as element, attribute etc), not what type of data is contained within it.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I would create an object and Serialize\Deserialize to\from XML like so.....

```
using System;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace _37321906
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Root root = new Root();
            root.Data.Struct.PartnerCD = 123;
            root.Data.Struct.UserName = "api";
            root.Data.Struct.Password = "pass";
            root.Data.Struct.Action = "token";
            root.Data.Struct.Token = 4847898;
            root.Data.Struct.Products.Product.Add(new Product { ProductID = 123, SVA = "e8a8227c-bba3-4f32-a2cd-15e8f246344b", Amount = 700.0001 });

            // Serialize the root object to XML
            Serialize<Root>(root);

            // Deserialize from XML
            Root DeserializeRoot = Deserialize<Root>();
        }

        private static void Serialize<T>(T data)
        {

            // Use a file stream here.
            using (TextWriter WriteFileStream = new StreamWriter("test.xml"))
            {
                // Construct a SoapFormatter and use it  
                // to serialize the data to the stream.
                XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));

                try
                {
                    // Serialize EmployeeList to the file stream
                    SerializerObj.Serialize(WriteFileStream, data);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
                }
            }
        }

        private static T Deserialize<T>() where T : new()
        {
            //List<Employee> EmployeeList2 = new List<Employee>();
            // Create an instance of T
            T ReturnListOfT = CreateInstance<T>();


            // Create a new file stream for reading the XML file
            using (FileStream ReadFileStream = new FileStream("test.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            {
                // Construct a XmlSerializer and use it  
                // to serialize the data from the stream.
                XmlSerializer SerializerObj = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
                try
                {
                    // Deserialize the hashtable from the file
                    ReturnListOfT = (T)SerializerObj.Deserialize(ReadFileStream);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Failed to serialize. Reason: {0}", ex.Message));
                }

            }
            // return the Deserialized data.
            return ReturnListOfT;
        }

        // function to create instance of T
        public static T CreateInstance<T>() where T : new()
        {
            return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
        }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Product")]
    public class Product
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ProductID")]
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "SVA")]
        public string SVA { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Amount")]
        public double Amount { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Products")]
    public class Products
    {
        public Products()
        {
            this.Product = new List<Product>();
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Product")]
        public List<Product> Product { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "struct")]
    public class Struct
    {
        public Struct()
        {
            this.Products = new Products();
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "PartnerCD")]
        public int PartnerCD { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "UserName")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Action")]
        public string Action { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "OfficeCD")]
        public string OfficeCD { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "ChannelCD")]
        public string ChannelCD { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Token")]
        public int Token { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Notes")]
        public string Notes { get; set; }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "Products")]
        public Products Products { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "data")]
    public class Data
    {
        public Data()
        {
            this.Struct = new Struct();
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "struct")]
        public Struct Struct { get; set; }
    }

    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
    public class Root
    {
        public Root()
        {
            this.Data = new Data();
        }
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }
}
```

find your XML in the build folder called test.xml